# Get key with minimum value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this: `arr = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49, …}`

And I'm trying get the lowest value with key using Javascript.

What I've tried:

`alert(Math.min.apply(Math, arr));` returns `Infinity` I don't know why

I got this on Google, just for try:

```
var keys = Object.keys(arr).map(Number).filter(function(a){
    return arr[a];
}); alert(Math.min.apply(Math, keys));
```

returns `Infinity` too

I want something more complete, like this output: "The lowest value is 2 from lst9".

I really tried fix it myself before asking here, but without success!
Can you help me fix this "Infinity" issue? Thank you.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Do you want to get, for example, `lst3` if `obj.lst3` is the lowest value?

Comment: Also, what is `lst9`? Is it `lst9: 2`?

Comment: may be a duplicte of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008307/get-key-from-a-javascript-object-with-minimum-value

Comment: Just write down a for loop for this. You can iterate objects with for loop too.

Comment: As @SyedMehtabHassan said. Particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008435/5237164

Comment: `arr` is not an array but an `object`

Comment: Are we supposed to edit this question to change "array" into object/hash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get key from a javascript object with minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008307/get-key-from-a-javascript-object-with-minimum-value)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the key and value using `Object.entries`:

```js
var arr = {
  lst1: 300,
  lst2: 381,
  lst3: 4,
  lst4: 4,
  lst5: 49
};

function lowestValueAndKey(obj) {
  var [lowestItems] = Object.entries(obj).sort(([ ,v1], [ ,v2]) => v1 - v2);
  return `Lowest value is ${lowestItems[1]}, with a key of ${lowestItems[0]}`;
}

var lowest = lowestValueAndKey(arr);
console.log(lowest);
```

Comment: Hello, Are there an way to make this script compatible with Internet Explorer too?

Comment: @Mernt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill

Comment: I tried but I'm getting a syntax error on line `var lowestItems = Object.entries(arr).sort(([ ,v1], [ ,v2]) => v1 - v2)[0]`

Comment: If you look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries you'll see that Internet Explorer does not support `Object.entries`

Comment: @Mernt IE doesn't support the fat arrow notation. You need to rewrite `([ ,v1], [ ,v2]) => v1 - v2` in old style Javascript

Comment: Good answer but using `Array.prototype.reduce()` instead of `Array.prototype.sort()` will be more performant.. And also, you are not preventing if the object `arr` do not contains any key value pairs..

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I think you meant JackBashford

Comment: Ups @JollyJoker, your right.. Sorry.. Updated my comment ;)

Comment: I really don't know how do that @JollyJoker, I tried but without success =[

Comment: @Mernt `function(a,b) {return a[1]-b[1]}`

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to arrive at what you want. Please see the following methods:

```js
const obj = { lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49 }
const values = Object.values(obj)
const lowest = Math.min.apply(null, values)

// Using Object.keys(), Object.values() and findIndex()
const keys = Object.keys(obj)
const indexOfLowest = values.findIndex(function (x) { return x === lowest })
console.log(`The lowest value is ${lowest} from ${keys[indexOfLowest]}`)



// OR Using Object.keys() and filter()
const key = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (x) { return obj[x] === lowest })[0]
console.log(`The lowest value is ${lowest} from ${key}`)



// OR Using Object.entries() and sort()
const [[lowestKey, lowestVal]] = Object.entries(obj).sort(function ([,valA], [,valB]) { return valA - valB });
console.log(`The lowest value is ${lowestVal} from ${lowestKey}`)
```

Comment: Syntax error on line `var key = Object.keys(arr).filter(x => arr[x] === lowest)[0]`

Comment: I'll suggest using a polyfill if it doesn't work in IE. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill

I should also inform you that on my IE on Windows 10 it works without needing a polyfill.

Comment: @JohnKennedy I'd be surprised by that, IE doesn't support arrow functions

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to approach your problem, but here is one simple alternative way to do it. Basically, it is a brute force way of doing things, whereby you iterate through every property to check for the value.

```
const obj = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49};

const getSmallest = function (object) {
  let smallestValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  let selectedKey = '';
  for (let key in object) {
    if (object[key] < smallestValue) {
      smallestValue = object[key];
      selectedKey = key;
    }
  }; 
  console.log(selectedKey, smallestValue)
  return `The lowest value is ${smallestValue} from ${selectedKey}`;
};

getSmallest(obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

To get only the minimum number you can use `Math.min(...Object.entries(arr).map(o => o[1]))`:

```js
const arr = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49};
const lowestValue = Math.min(...Object.entries(arr).map(o => o[1]));

console.log(lowestValue);
```

And to get the object with the minimum value you can use `Object.entries(arr).reduce((a, [k, v]) => a[Object.keys(a)[0]] < v ? a : {[k]: v}, {})`:

```js
const arr = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49};
const lowestObj = Object.entries(arr).reduce((a, [k, v]) => a[Object.keys(a)[0]] < v ? a : {[k]: v}, {});

console.log(lowestObj);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here we first assume that the min, key and value as first property and the value respectively. Then we iterate through all the elements and compare with minValue to find any value less than that in the object. If it is, then we update both minValue and minKey. Anyway, the arr type is an Object. it is not an array in javascript.

```
var arr = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49};
var minkey = Object.keys(arr)[0];
var minValue = arr[Object.keys(arr)[0]];
for (var key in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(arr[key] < minValue){
           minValue = arr[key];
           minKey = key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
obj = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49, lst9: 2}; // This is an object, That;s ehy you getting infinite

var arr = Object.keys( obj ).map(function ( key ) { return obj[key]; });

alert(Math.min.apply( null, arr ));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ozvubmdr/

Answer (score 2):

Easy, though not optimal, as it traverses the array twice: find the smallest value, then find the key belonging to it.

```js
arr = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49, lst9: 2}
min = Math.min(...Object.values(arr));
minkey = Object.keys(arr).find(key => arr[key] = min);
console.log(`Lowest is ${min} at ${minkey}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```js
const arr = {lst1: 300, lst2: 381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49, lst9: 2}
const minVal = Math.min(...Object.values(arr))
const fromKey = Object.keys(arr).find(key => arr[key] === minVal)
console.log(`The lowest value is ${minVal} from ${fromKey}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.entries` and use `Array.reduce` to reduce the resulting [key-value] pair to an object which will have lowest entry:

```js
const data = {lst1: 300, lst2: -381, lst3: 4, lst4: 4, lst5: 49, lst6: -49, lst7: 0, lst7: 78, lst7: -90};
const obj = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>{
  acc["lowest"] = acc["lowest"] ?  Object.values(acc["lowest"])[0] < value ? acc["lowest"] : {[key] : value} : {[key] : value };
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(`Lowest value is found in  ${JSON.stringify(obj.lowest)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to keep track of the minimal pair as you go:

```js
const findKeyForMin = obj => Object.entries(obj).reduce(([accKey, accVal], [curKey, curVal]) =>
    /* Change `<` to `<=` to find the last minimum instead of the first minimum. */
    curVal < accVal ? [curKey, curVal] : [accKey, accVal]
)[0];
```